# Does capybara ignore code in a before(:all) block? What can I do about this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I completely understand why you should use before(:each) and make all expectations independent of each other, but I'm just interested into why this would happen:

```
before(:each) { visit "/" } # Selenium visits the root path of my app
before(:all) { visit "/" } # Selenium doesn't even open firefox.
```

Nothing happens with the `background(:all)`, but if I raise an exception in the same context, Selenium does open firefox and visits this weird empty file.

```
file:///home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/empty.html
```

So does anyone know if Capybara actively ignores code in a before block(:all), and if so, **how can I get it to not ignore code in a before(:all)?**

This isn't really serious project, but I was thinking about benchmarking with Capybara, so it would be nice if someone showed me a way to get Capybara working with a before(:all).

Comment: +1 for pulling this out as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinct difference in these two `before` blocks.

`before(:each)` is evaluated before every test.

`before(:all)` is evaluated before running your tests. Once.

You should probably be using `before(:each)`

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't even run once for me. Say I have one test in my context. The `block(:each)` visits `/` and the view I have hooked up to it, but the `block(:all)` visits `<...>/lib/capybara/empty.html`. Bit odd isn't it?

Comment: You're missing the point I think. `before(:all)` should only be used when setting something up which isn't wiped out after every test. On the whole, you should be using `before(:each)`